# PDO the letter 'n' is deleted and not entered into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, string, pdo

I was really hoping someone would be able to help me with this weird issue I'm having.  The issue is, when I enter the word **"down"** into my *MySQL* table, the last letter **"n"** is left off of the string leaving me with the word **"dow"** stored in the table.  I have no idea why this would happen. The only thing I could think of, is that the next string stored in my table is the word "no" which starts with **"n"**.

```
<?php
$machine_status = $_POST["status"];
$is_original    = $_POST["original"];
$query = "INSERT INTO `table` (id,machine_status,original_machine,datetime) VALUES (?,?,?,?);
$enter_data = $db->prepare($query);
$enter_data->bindValue(1,NULL,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$enter_data->bindParam(2,$machine_status,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$enter_data->bindParam(3,$is_original,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$enter_data->bindValue(4,NULL,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$enter_data->execute();
?>
```

I simplified the length of the query and the try/catch statements, if you need more of my surrounding code please let me know.

so the data that I get is all there except for the machine_status field... I get:

> id: 0, machine_status: "dow", original: "no",datetime: 2013-12-30 05:53:47

notice the missing "n" at the end of "down"

Comment: What field type/length is the machine status column?

Comment: Can you post the schema definition?

Comment: The column where you insert "down" is varchar ? longer than 3 chars ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the size of the column that 'down' is being inserted into only can hold three characters, than 'down' will be truncated to 'dow' and a warning will be emitted.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can't believe I overlooked that.

Comment: Consider using MySQL strict mode (might be called something different)